# Automating the deployment process of plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin, when I deploy it, I use a feature project then export through the wizard to get zip file to install in any eclipse based app.

How can I automate this ?

I want the whole process to run automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PDE Build stuff](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/automation.html), also see the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/automation.html).